# Do auto generated core data accessors automatically delete objects?

Tags: objective-c, macos, core-data

Say you've got entity A, and it has a to-many relationship with entity B. If i use the auto-generated accessor `[entityA removeEntityBObject:entityB];`, is entityB deleted or simply removed from entityA?

If it doesn't auto delete, is there a way to make it do so?

Answer (score -1):

In your core data model, there's a field call "Delete Rule" for relationship.

You can choose Cascade, Nullify, Deny and No Action. Check the documentation for detail of what each of them do.

Comment: This is not what i was talking about. Relationship delete rules only work if the parent entity is DELETED.